# Vue.js - Element UI - Nested dialog won't open - v-if v-show

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue.js 2.3` and `element-ui`

#### Situation

I'm just playing around with the `el-dialog` component. I'm testing 3 differents options and only one out of the three is working

`<popup v-if="showDialog" :show-dialog.sync="showDialog"></popup>` OK

`<popup v-show="showDialog" :show-dialog.sync="showDialog"></popup>` PARTIAL OK

`<popup :show-dialog.sync="showDialog"></popup>` NOT OK

#### Code

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showDialog = true">Show Component PopUp</button>
  <popup v-if="showDialog" :show-dialog.sync="showDialog"></popup>
</div>



   <template id="popup">
        <el-dialog :visible.sync="show" @visible-change="updateShowDialog" >{{data}}</el-dialog>
    </template>

Vue.component('popup', {
    name: "popup",
  template: '#popup',
  props : ['showDialog'],
  data(){
    return {
        show: this.showDialog,
      data: "Hello"
    }
  },
  methods: {
   updateShowDialog(isVisible) {
       if (isVisible) return false;
       this.$emit('update:showDialog', false )
   }
  },
   created:function (){
  },
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showDialog: false,
  },
  methods: {

  }
});
```

#### Fiddles

https://jsfiddle.net/dbg2e9z2/ OK

https://jsfiddle.net/gtxeaq41/ PARTIAL OK

https://jsfiddle.net/dwr5dmfg/ NOT OK

#### Problems

With the 2nd option, the pop-up opens but the content is not displayed.
With the 3rd option, the pop-up is not displayed at all.

#### Questions

Why this behavior?

What should I do to have the `el-dialog` working normally while avoiding the `v-if` (I want to keep the data in cache since the dialog contains a lot of data)

Comment: I don't understand very well what do you want to achieve. Anyway with watch you can avoid using v-if, v-show.. See this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/64Ltkne7/)

Comment: I want to display or hide the `dialog` depending on 'showDialog' but I do not want `mounted` to be triggered each time I `open` `close` the `dialog` cause I have lot a computation happening on rendering. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Max answer https://jsfiddle.net/64Ltkne7/

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showDialog = true">Show Component PopUp</button>
  <popup :show-dialog.sync="showDialog"></popup>
</div>

<template id="popup">
    <el-dialog :visible.sync="show" @visible-change="updateShowDialog" >{{data}}</el-dialog>
</template>

console.clear()

let popupData;

Vue.component('popup', {
    name: "popup",
  template: '#popup',
  props : ['showDialog'],
  data(){
    return {
        show: this.showDialog,
      data: "Hello"
    }
  },
  watch: {
    showDialog: function(n,o){
            this.show = this.showDialog;    
    }
  },
  methods: {
   updateShowDialog(isVisible) {
       if (isVisible) return false;
       this.$emit('update:showDialog', false )
   }
  },
   mounted:function (){
   alert('mounted')
  },
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showDialog: false,
  },
  methods: {

  }
});
```